# Limit serializer by user

Tags: django

Here is my model serializer:

```py
class FoodImagesSerializerGet(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    current_user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    food = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=False, read_only=False,slug_field='id', queryset=Food.objects.filter(users=current_user)
    )
```

Model:

```py
class FoodImages(models.Model):
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, related_name='food_images', related_query_name='food_image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
class Food(models.Model):
        users = models.ManyToManyField(
        Profile,
        related_name='userfoods',
        related_query_name='userfood',
    )
```

I want to limit the serializer by users so only the users of the food can post images
.
I want to do that Just with the SlugRelatedField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override SlugRelatedField like this:

```
class CustomSlugRelatedField(SlugRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(users=self.context['request'].user)

class FoodImagesSerializerGet(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    food = CustomSlugRelatedField(
        many=False, read_only=False,slug_field='id', queryset=Food.objects.all()
    )
```

Finally, you need to pass the `request` via [context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) in the serializer. This is taken cared by the [GenericViews](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) and ModelViewSets automatically, for function based view, you can try like this:

```
serializer = FoodImagesSerializerGet(Food.objects.first(), context={'request': request})
```

Comment: Is there any other cleaner method? I mean I prefer to don't touch the views

Comment: As far as I know, the view part is standard implementation, also same thing is being implemented in Generic Views which are provided by DRF. But, there might be multiple options for implementing the override in serializer. Either way, you need user object in serializer to make it work. Context is the standard way to provide it from view to serializer.

Comment: I'm using a ModelViewSet and cann't pass request like this

Comment: its already taken care of by ModelViewSet. You won't have to,

Comment: Since serializer is a class attribute I can't pass request to ir\t

Comment: I meant that you don't have to do anything or make any changes in the ViewSet. Because internally viewset sends request object to serializer.

Comment: TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got HiddenField(default=CurrentUserDefault()).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251516/discussion-between-leviathan-and-ruddra).

Answer (score 1):

it's a class attribute, it couldn't access to request context on runtime. You have to access it via `init` method

```py
class FoodImagesSerializerGet(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    current_user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    food = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=False, read_only=False,slug_field='id', queryset=Food.objects.all()
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['food'].queryset = Food.objects.filter(users=self.context['request'].user)
```

Comment: TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got HiddenField(default=CurrentUserDefault()).

Comment: @Leviathan ah remove the old qs, you actually provide it on init

Comment: AttributeError: 'FoodImagesSerializerGet' object has no attribute 'parent'

Comment: f* me forgot `super` as well LOL